# How to find the location where Spark stores all the config values

Tags: apache-spark

I am new to Spark & learning its internal's, one of the things of Spark that is eluding to me is how the spark session gets all the config properties. I want to collect all the Spark config including the default ones too. I can easily find the ones explicitly set in the spark-session and also by looking into spark-defaults.conf file by running a small code like below

configurations = spark.sparkContext.getConf().getAll()
for item in configurations: print(item)

My question is where does Spark pick the rest of the default parameters, is there a default location that Spark distribution maintains internally that is not exposed to the user.

eg : spark.conf.get("spark.sql.adaptive.enabled") give me "true" as an output. But if I do a find in the root directory, I can't seem the find the value present in any of the physical files on the server

find / -name "*.*" 2>/dev/null -exec grep -li "spark.sql.adaptive.enabled" '{}' ;

Return nothing :(

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Regards,
Pankaj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the code, default values which are not in the conf file is embedded in spark code.

[This](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/internal/SQLConf.scala) is the SparkSql default conf value code